# Jquery animate divs eq() method is off

Tags: jquery

I have a div with 20 divs inside of it. What I am doing is starting with div:eq(1) and swapping it with the one to the left then repeating div:eq(2), div:eq(3), etc and swapping to the left.

It seems the DOM does not update correctly after this as they are always off by 1 after this.

I thought maybe cloning the div after animation completes would work but it does'nt.

It seems the DOM does not live update it's structure?
**EDIT**
Sorry for not initially providing code. As you can see after the first swap it uses the "old" div.

http://jsfiddle.net/vrCUT/

```
$(function () {


    var currentIndex = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            $("#holder").append('<div class="number">' + i + '</div>');
   }


    function resetDivs(){
    $("#holder div").css("border", "");
    }
    prepareForSwap();
    function prepareForSwap() {
        currentIndex++;
        resetDivs();
        div2 = $("#holder").find("div:eq(" + currentIndex + ")");
        div1 = div2.prev();

        div1.css("border", "3px solid blue");
        div2.css("border", "3px solid red");
        setTimeout(swap, 2000);

    }

    function swap() {
        div1.animate({
            left: "+=25"
        }, 2000, function () {
        });


        div2.animate({
            left: "-=25"
        }, 2000, function () {
            if(currentIndex < 20){
            setTimeout(prepareForSwap,2000);
            }
        });


   }
    );
```

Comment: AND!!! where is your related  code ??

Comment: `eq` is zero based. Whether that's the issue I cannot say.

Comment: Can you add some of your code and a js fiddle that can recreate the problem ?

Comment: I will get a jsfiddle up. Give me a few ticks

Comment: I had the wrong JsFiddle it is corrected now.

Comment: I don't mean the code is corrected. I mean I had the wrong jsfiddle listed. I still have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Start it from `div:eq(0)` till `div:eq(19)`

Comment: I do not think that is the issue. I have added a demo with some code.